# Authenticate Wifi using gmail and Pfsense

Tags: authentication, gmail, wifi, radius

My teacher told me to deploy a wifi hotspot that authenticate wifi user using gmail address from Google. He also talked about Pfsense, radius. I don't know where to start, what technologies relate to this. Help me!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any programming question here. Maybe that's why it's gone unanswered for so long. Meanwhile, there are 1,128 search resuults for [pfsense](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pfsense) on Server Fault, so maybe this question belongs there?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do it is to use the built-in user manager of pfSense. You need to add all their email addresses as username, then passwords, and assign their respective privileges (eg. to connect to internet only).

Enable Captive Portal which on default requires username and password, and you're good to go!

Regards,
Reward